# Coefficient of correlation between two variables

Tags: correlation

If the coefficient of correlation between two variables is 0.7 then the percentage variation unaccounted for is?

Answer (score 1):

The "percentage of variance accounted for" is the square of the correlation...

So, $0.7^2 = 0.49 \rightarrow 49$% of variance explained.

A correlation coefficient of 1 explains the all of the variability in the dependent variable.

Comment: But in answer they gave 51%

Comment: I have you % of variance *explained*.  Your question is asking for % of variance *unexplained*.  This site is for assistance with problems, not homework help. 
 $1.00 - 0.49 = 0.51 = 51$%